# Is my site hacked?

Tags: security, iis-7, web

I have my client website www.healthiva.com..  this is developed in .Net C#. In global.asax i have a functionality to send alert email to development team, if any unhandled exceptions are thrown in the whole application. Some times dev team gets email like "The file '/ivr/VAD_Deploy1.aspx' does not exist", "The file '/ivr/mxm_3cx/mxm30.aspx' does not exist"..   Our application does not have these files obviously & hence the error.  Now my worry is, is someone trying to hack our site by running some scripts ? if yes, please suggest some good security policies.. (the site already uses SSL)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are safe

I've just done a couple of tests to see, and it appears that you are getting these errors because other resources in your application are trying to access these directories. Rather than handle these errors and provide a user safe code, it's simply throwing a default server error. Your website is not being hacked - it's just badly written (Sorry, no offence) and lacks sufficient logging techniques.

*However*, that does not mean that you are still 100% safe. You can either consult with a private security expert or look at automated tools online to test the security of your website. I'd recommend doing some research on the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) for this, and how to prevent these measures. Most hackers will try to go for one of these methods before trying more robust and niché attacks.

EDIT: [Relevant image showing what happens when the server throws an exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MCTC.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I'm damn sure that my application is not trying to access these files..  That's the main reason I was bothered about security.. I'll go through the links provided by you, so that I can give more security to my site & learn few more things as well...